# how can i check if Website is currently available

Tags: delphi, https

I'm trying to get an exception when I try to download a file from a website. My current way is to download a `.zip` file from the website and check the file size of the `.zip`. I think that's not the best way to check if a website exists. Maybe some of you have a better idea for checking if a website is currently available, and if it isn't than get an error 404 exception.

Comment: Issue a HEAD command instead of a GET command. That'll force the web server to respond, but won't send any web-page/file. If you get a 404 (or a 200), it means that the web server is online. If you get a time-out, it isn't.

Comment: HTTP `404 Not Found` really is just that, not more, not less - it doesn't tell you there never will be a website, nor for how long nothing will be found. Also expect [`410 Gone` and `425 Too Early`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_client_errors) as responses.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

If you just want to know if there is something alive, just use a plain TCP socket and try to connection to port 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS). If the connection is successful, close it and assume a website is there.

If you want to be sure this is a website that responds, then you must issue an HTTP command that transfers the minimum data. You can send a `HEAD` command for that.

If you want to get a file, just try to get it, and check the status code for success or failure.

Comment: i've tried to use the HEAD command from TIdHttp but the problem is that my URL is a HTTPS and IdHttp is checking on port 80. Can you explain what you mean with "Check the status code" ?

Comment: @Daniel1999: If you issue a HEAD command to a URL that starts with https:// TIdHttp will connect at port 443 (unless you explicitly specify a port address in the URL). But make sure you have the SSL libraries available, and an IOHandler set up in your TIdHttp instance.

Comment: yeah and im currently not using the SSL libraries or an IOHandler. Is there maybe another way to check if the URL is currently available? like checking the Filesize of the Zip

Comment: @Daniel1999: You cannot check if a URL on an https connection using TIdHttp is available without SSL libraries. You can check if there's a program listening on port 443, but any communication that you initiate on that connection, must be secured by TLS (SSL). You could switch to using built-in Windows http(s) libraries instead of TIdHttp - that way you can use Windows' own https libraries.

Comment: @fpiette talked somethink about to check the Status Code of the file. I Think thats a good Solution for me. Does anyone know how to check a Status from a zip file?

Comment: @Daniel1999: The status code he's referring to is the status code that the http server gives you. Normally a "200 OK" or "404 Not Found". But that still requires that you have a TLS-protected communication up and running for https connections - otherwise the server will never see your request.

Comment: @Daniel1999 HeartWare is correct for the status code and other subjects. I won't repeat what he said.

Comment: @Daniel1999 "*the problem is that my URL is a HTTPS and IdHttp is checking on port 80*" - that is not how `TIdHTTP` works. It will always check HTTPS on port 443 unless the URL explicitly states to use a different port. "*im currently not using the SSL libraries or an IOHandler*" - then you can't even request an HTTPS url to begin with, an `EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid` exception will be raised. you MUST use an `SSLIOHandler` in order to use HTTPS.

Comment: @HeartWare "*You could switch to using built-in Windows http(s) libraries instead of TIdHttp - that way you can use Windows' own https libraries*" - or, you can write a custom `SSLIOHandler` (or find a 3rd party one) that uses OS-provided TLS APIs (ie, SChannel on Windows), or other 3rd party TLS libraries that don't depend on external DLLs (ie, SecureBlackbox, libTLS, etc).